# Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Player

Tags: java

Here is the code. Not sure whats wrong. Happens at the line that says

```java
for (Player players : World.getPlayers()) {
    if (cmd[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ticket")) {
        if (player.getRights() > 0) {
            if (World.getTicketList().size() == 0) {
                player.getPackets().sendGameMessage("No one needs help so sit back and relax.");
                return true;
            }
            String username = World.getTicketList().get(0).toString();
            Player p2 = World.getPlayer(username);
            player.setNextWorldTile(p2);
            p2.getPackets().sendGameMessage("Please ask your question to " + Misc.formatPlayerNameForDisplay(player.getUsername()) + ".");
            World.remoteTicket(username.toLowerCase());
            return true;
        }
        if (World.getTicketList().contains(player.getUsername().toLowerCase())) {
            player.getPackets().sendGameMessage("You already submitted a ticket.", true);
            return true;
        }
        World.addToTicket(player.getUsername());
        player.getPackets().sendGameMessage("Your ticket has been submitted. Your ticket number is " + World.getTicketId(player.getUsername()) + 1 + ".");
        player.getPackets().sendGameMessage("Make sure that you are not in a PvP area..");
        String username = World.getTicketList().get(0).toString();
        for (Player players : World.getPlayers()) {
            if (player.getRights() > 0) {
                players.getPackets().sendGameMessage(Misc.formatPlayerNameForDisplay(player.getUsername()) + " has issued a assistance request.", true);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here is the code for getPlayers

```java
public static final EntityList getPlayers() {
    return players;
}
```

Comment: Post your definition of EntityList.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that whatever World.getPlayers() returns implements java.lang.Iterable

Comment: Thanks, That did not work though
Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
I'll Post the code.

Comment: Whoops. Cast to Player [], not Player. I've edited the post. Try that.

Comment: Hmm, still doesnt seem to work. Get this now, Cannot cast from EntityList to Player[]

Comment: I think we need to know more about what EntityList is and where you're getting it from.

Comment: Is EntityList implemented by you? Does it implement the java.lang.Iterable interface? If not, it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in the for loop. Change it to

```
for (Object player : World.getPlayers()) {
     if (((Player)player).getRights() > 0)
         players.getPackets().sendGameMessage(Misc.formatPlayerNameForDisplay(player.getUsername())+" has issued a assistance request.", true);
     }
}
```

That should work.